# influxdb continuous query to move data to a retention policy selecting multiple values with many transforms

Tags: influxdb, retention

Hi I'm trying to do a continuous query in version 1.8 of influxDB. I'm noticing none of the documentation works, firstly because i need to enter the continuous query into the terminal with no return characters (documentation shows return characters probably to make it easier to read), but also putting a comma and adding another select statement gives me a parse error. Here's my command and the parser error:

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY "old_data_cc" ON "admin" BEGIN SELECT mean("value") as "mean", SELECT min("value") as "min", SELECT max("value") as "max" INTO "old_data" FROM "default" GROUP BY time(1h) END
```

**ERR: error parsing query: found SELECT, expected identifier, string, number, bool at line 1, char 84**

Comment: WHy are you using multiple selects? Try:  `CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY "old_data_cc" ON "admin" BEGIN SELECT mean("value") as "mean",  min("value") as "min", max("value") as "max" INTO "old_data" FROM "default" GROUP BY time(1h) END`

Comment: @YuriLachin It works doing with your advice. If you'd like to post that as the answer I'll gladly accept your response. I put in multiple selects because i thought each new line needed to start with an action keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple `SELECT`s aren't needed. Try:

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY "old_data_cc" ON "admin" BEGIN SELECT mean("value") as "mean", min("value") as "min", max("value") as "max" INTO "old_data" FROM "default" GROUP BY time(1h) END
```